# oracle proc to update one table using another via dblink

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, debugging

I keep running into this execution error when running my stored procedure. It is supposed to select some values from table 1 into a few variables, use those in a select that uses a db link and gets a value from that linked db table 2 then updates the first table.

> [Error] Execution (1: 2): ORA-01403: no data found
>   ORA-06512: at "ASSGN_OF_ID", line 24
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ASSGN_OF_ID
IS
  v_transID varchar2 (30);
  v_person_id NUMBER (12);
  v_long_id NVARCHAR2 (15);
  v_tranactions_date date;
  v_assgn_id varchar2 (30);
  v_t_emp_id varchar2 (30);
BEGIN
  select max(transID) into v_transID from tranactions;
--
  select personid, tranactionsdtm into v_person_id, v_tranactions_date
  from tranactions
  where transID = v_transID;
--
  select lirrnum into v_long_id
  from ptsadmin.person
  where personid = v_person_id;
--
  select emp_mstr_id into v_t_emp_id
  from wok.emp_mstr@T_DBLINK
  where emp_nbr = v_long_id;
--
  select asgn_id into v_assgn_id
  from wok.slip_mstr@T_DBLINK
  where emp_mstr_id = v_t_emp_id
  and trunc(v_tranactions_date) = trunc(eff_date_time);
--
  update tranactions set t_asgn_id = v_assgn_id where transID = v_transID;
--
  COMMIT;
END;
```

It gets stopped on this line

```
select emp_mstr_id into v_t_emp_id
from wok.emp_mstr@T_DBLINK
where emp_nbr = v_long_id;
```

I don't see how there isn't data if the lines before it run and if I run the statements with pre-defined values they work.

Comment: I suggest using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` to print the values that are assigned to the variables.

Comment: You tagged this for MySQL but it doesn't appear that MySQL is being used anywhere.  This looks to be a PL/SQL procedure in Oracle.  What does "it gets stopped" mean?  That the code blocks?  That it throws an error?  If so, what error?

Comment: i swear i actually know stuff until i come here and ask, i figured it out using that output line, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` showed me what was going wrong, stupid me, thanks everyone